# Height and Distance problems

Tags: trigonometry

A ladder rests against a wall at an angle $\alpha$ to the horizontal. When its foot is pulled away from the wall through a distance $a$, it slides a distance $b$ down the wall and makes an angle $\beta$ with the horizontal. Prove that :
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha-\sin\beta}$$.

I tried to solve this question as;
Let $AB$ be a wall and $AC$ be the ladder. Then $\angle ACB=\alpha$. Now, the question says, "when its foot is pulled", I doubt that whether the ladder is pulled in sideways direction or in downward direction.

Comment: Please show us exactly *what* you have tried, and then we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @Lovsovs, please see the updated one..

Comment: The foot of the ladder is pulled away from the wall in the horizontal direction if we see the scenario from the side (which you do to with your triangle $ABC$), so that the ladder is "more close" to lying down after the pull.

Comment: @Lovos, could you give a bit more hints

Comment: Oh that wasn't a hint, just an interpretation of the problem... I don't see how to prove it myself unfortunately, if it is even true. I end up with some very nasty expressions, so I can't help you. Best of luck!

Comment: @Iaamuseruser this might help http://www.cbseguess.com/ebooks/x/maths/part2/chapter13b.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Sketch of the problem]

We have $(a+x)^2+y^2=x^2+(b+y)^2$ (as they are both equal to the length of the ladder). And $\tan\alpha=\frac{b+y}{x}$ and $\tan\beta=\frac{y}{a+x}$. Eliminating $x,y$ between these three equation, we get
$$
a^2 \tan (\beta )+2 a b-b^2 \tan (\beta )=\tan (\alpha ) \left(-a^2+2 a b \tan (\beta )+b^2\right)\ .
$$
Dividing both sides by $ab$, we get
$$
(a/b) \tan (\beta )+2 -(b/a) \tan (\beta )=\tan (\alpha ) \left(-(a/b)+2  \tan (\beta )+(b/a)\right)\ .
$$
Setting $a/b=\xi$, this is equivalent to
$$
\xi \tan (\beta )+2 -(1/\xi) \tan (\beta )=\tan (\alpha ) \left(-\xi+2  \tan (\beta )+(1/\xi)\right)\ ,
$$
which can be solved for $\xi$.

**EDIT:** Solving for $\xi$, one obtains two solutions:$\xi=-\mathrm{cot}((\alpha+\beta)/2)$ (which is not acceptable because, for $0<\alpha+\beta<\pi$
it gives a *negative* value for the ratio $a/b$), and $\xi=\tan((\alpha+\beta)/2)$. Then, using a tangent of half-angle formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula I can write this as
$$
\xi=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\cos\beta-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha-\sin\beta}\ ,
$$
i.e. with a minus sign difference with respect to the solution posted by the OP, which seems in fact incorrect. Take for example the case $\alpha=\pi/4$ and $\beta=\pi/6$. Then we have $x=b+y=L/\sqrt{2}$, $y=L/2$ and $a+x=(L/2)\sqrt{3}$, if $L$ is the length of the ladder. Then, $a/b=-2-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6}\approx 0.76... $, while $\frac{\cos (\alpha )-\cos (\beta )}{\sin (\alpha )-\sin (\beta )}=\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}\right)\approx -0.76...$

Comment: How did you Eliminate x and Y?

Comment: @RAM Solve $\tan\alpha=\frac{b+y}{x}$ and $\tan\beta=\frac{y}{a+x}$ for $x,y$ and substitute back into $(a+x)^2+y^2=x^2+(b+y)^2$ (for example)...

Comment: @Pierpaolo, I could not get the required answer after I solve the equation?

Comment: @laamuser user I have edited the answer to spell out the solution in full.